# Visual Studio 2013 - How to open Source and Header automaticly at specific sides

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2013

I am usually having my source files on the left and my header files on the right. However, I always have to manually drag them to the right side after opening.

My question is: Is it possible to automate this process based on file extension?

Comment: Why is this tagged to `c++`? Please remove the `C++` tag.

Comment: I am looking for a solution in the particular case of c++. Given that other languages like c also follow the header / source pattern, you are right. Removed the tag.